# "cpanm PHP" fails

Tags: perl, centos, cpanm

What should I change in order to install the module? php is 5.3.3 with`yum install php-devel` in place.

```
PHP.c: In function ‘PHP_set_php_input’:
PHP.c:818: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘Perl_sv_2pv_flags’ from incompatible pointer type
/home/mpapec/.plenv/versions/5.20.0/lib/perl5/5.20.0/x86_64-linux/CORE/proto.h:3931: note: expected ‘STRLEN * const’ but argument is of type ‘int *’
cc -c  -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -Wall -O2   -DVERSION=\"0.15\" -DXS_VERSION=\"0.15\" -fPIC "-I/home/mpapec/.plenv/versions/5.20.0/lib/perl5/5.20.0/x86_64-linux/CORE"   array.c
In file included from /usr/include/php/main/php.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/php/sapi/embed/php_embed.h:23,
                 from PHP.h:14,
                 from array.c:9:
/usr/include/php/main/php_config.h:2417:1: warning: "_GNU_SOURCE" redefined
In file included from /home/mpapec/.plenv/versions/5.20.0/lib/perl5/5.20.0/x86_64-linux/CORE/perl.h:28,
                 from PHP.h:9,
                 from array.c:9:
/home/mpapec/.plenv/versions/5.20.0/lib/perl5/5.20.0/x86_64-linux/CORE/config.h:1825:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
rm -f blib/arch/auto/PHP/PHP.so
cc  -shared -O2 -L/usr/local/lib -fstack-protector PHP.o array.o  -o blib/arch/auto/PHP/PHP.so  \
                \

chmod 755 blib/arch/auto/PHP/PHP.so
"/home/mpapec/.plenv/versions/5.20.0/bin/perl5.20.0" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- PHP.bs blib/arch/auto/PHP/PHP.bs 644
Manifying 1 pod document
Running Mkbootstrap for PHP ()
chmod 644 "PHP.bs"
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 "/home/mpapec/.plenv/versions/5.20.0/bin/perl5.20.0" "-Iblib/lib" "-Iblib/arch" test.pl
1..79
not ok 1 - use_ok PHP
#   Failed test 'use_ok PHP'
#   at test.pl line 11.
not ok 2 - require PHP;
#   Failed test 'require PHP;'
#   at test.pl line 18.
#     Tried to require 'PHP'.
#     Error:  Attempt to reload PHP.pm aborted.
# Compilation failed in require at (eval 6) line 2.
not ok 3 - eval
#   Failed test 'eval'
#   at test.pl line 49.
Module PHP failed to load at blib/lib/PHP.pm line 80.
Module PHP failed to load at blib/lib/PHP.pm line 80.
END failed--call queue aborted at test.pl line 50.
# Looks like you planned 79 tests but ran 3.
# Looks like you failed 3 tests of 3 run.
# Looks like your test exited with 22 just after 3.
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 22
-> FAIL Installing PHP failed. See /home/mpapec/.cpanm/work/1440522239.12833/build.log for details. Retry with --force to force install it.
(
```

Comment: CPAN testers is down right now but the the sidebar on [metacpan](https://metacpan.org/pod/PHP) show 16/16 tests failing. So I'm guessing it's not just you.

Comment: yes, it doesn't look too good, I guess @mob has some idea how to solve it.

Comment: Did you build php from source, configured with `--enable-embed`? That's the only way I ever got it to work.

Comment: @mob tnx for feedback, I'll try that but don't know how to tell perl which php to pick up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`PHP`](https://metacpan.org/pod/PHP) is kind of fragile. It probably won't work out of the box with your system `php` installation, and may have trouble with 64-bit or multi-threaded versions of `perl`.

I have only ever gotten it to work on Linux. The latest version I have tried to use is 5.3.8 (back in 2013), though I remember things going smoothly from 5.2.x to 5.3.8.

I always build `php` from source, with this configuration:

```
./configure --enable-embed --with-zlib --with-openssl --with-mysql \
        --with-libdir=lib/i386-linux-gnu
```

`--enable-embed` is absolutely required, as the pod mentions, to build a PHP interpreter with the SAPI extension, and which then allows perl to manipulate the PHP interpreter through XS code. The other extensions were for other requirements of my project; they may be optional, but I haven't experimented with building the PHP interpreter or the PHP module with any other configuration. The pod also says to never use the `--with-apxs` argument, which I was never tempted to do anyway.

The build process of the `PHP` module will look for and require a program called `php-config`. You may need to hack your `$PATH`, if only during the build process, so that the `PHP` module runs the correct `php-config`. After that the module will know where to look for the rest of your php installation.

I had fun working with this module for a while (writing a Catalyst and then a Mojolicious wrapper around WordPress), but it has fallen into disrepair and disrepute. Share whatever you learn trying to build it and we'll put it in the docs, making this module that much easier to use.

Comment: Tnx a lot, I'm also looking to use it with mojolicious.

Comment: Much to my surprise I've built 64bit versions of both perl/php and `PHP-0.15` installs without complaints. Where should I expect troubles? (perl is built without thread support)

Comment: 64 bit is ok, I think. I think I was confused because all my previous tests with 64-bit versions were also configured with threading.